# Curl error does not resolve my host but it does it with google

Tags: ubuntu, curl, server, centos, ping

I'm having an issue with curl, right now I'm running to dedicated servers with proxmox on them. in the first dedicated server I got my website and doing CURL from it (from the vps) does resolve google.es but it does not resolve my domain (panel.roozservers.com) the error that I'm getting it is Could not resolve host: panel.roozservers.com; UInknow error

[image]

Doing curl from an online curl tool will give the correct results so I figured out that its a problem on my machine. [image: https://reqbin.com/curl]

My /etc/resolv.conf file it is

```
# --- BEGIN PVE ---
search ip-54-39-131.net
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.186.33.99
# --- END PVE ---
```

My /etc/hosts file it is

```
127.0.1.1       LXC_NAME
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
# --- BEGIN PVE ---
51.161.31.150 RSWeb.ip-54-39-131.net RSWeb
# --- END PVE ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there’s issues curling or resolving a link to the machine your trying to resolve it from.

I can curl the domain just fine with a status code 200.

Try to curl from another machine or when not connected via ssh.

**EDIT**:

Open your hosts file with

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

Append this line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost panel.roozservers.com
```

Check if loopback ping works with:

```
ping "$(hostname)"
```

Try again to curl your domain from the same machine:

```
curl panel.roozservers.com
```

Comment: Curl from another machine and internet works. But curl from that machine it will not work. I'm not sure why. Curl from that machine (RSWeb) will not curl any of my domains but curling from another machine on the same dedicated server will work with no rpoblems.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by curling the machine from the machine itself?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate a gamepanel with my domain, for that to do I need curl to resolve panel.roozservers.com but for some reason its not working. I realize that the Host file in the other machine its different, copied to RSWeb but aint working either

Comment: It’s all on the same machine, right? Is there no other way to obtain the data?

Comment: Nope, theres is no other way. The panel is on Dedicated server 2 and the RSWeb is on Dedicated server 1, both are VPS virtualized with proxmox

Comment: By the way RSWeb is Centos, The other machine that I tried and Panel are ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is it a php script you’re curling from?

Comment: Yes it is from WHMCS, but also curling from the shell on RSWeb wont work.

Comment: No, not really because they are not in the same server :(

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it creating a new instance (VM).